# JavaScript Onkeyup expiry date

Tags: javascript, html

How can i set onkeyup to output this format  00/00 instead 00/00/0000

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="
    var v = this.value;
    if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
        this.value = v + '/';
    } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
        this.value = v + '/';
   }">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `maxlength="5"`

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="5" onkeyup="
    var v = this.value;
    this.value = v
      .replace(/^(\d{2})(?:\/?)(\d{1,2})$/, `$1/$2`)
      .replace(/^(\d{2})\/$/, '$1');
   ">
```

I also improved your regex to use `replace` and remove the `/` automatically